# EF Core Entity with Primary Key but without Clustered Index

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

For Entity Framework, when we have a primary Key on the Entity, EF always generates a clustered index.

```
public class TestEntity
{
    [key]
    public int NaturalKeyId;

    public string Field2;
    public string Field3;
}
```

The `NaturalKeyId` field will form a clustered index.

Is there a way to retain it as the (unique) primary key, but not have it as a clustered index? Before I get trolled, I agree that it is generally better to have a clustered index on a monotonously increasing (surrogate) `Id` field. However in a specific case, all update operations are always using the NaturalKey (there is no convenient Id passed in for the Update. **Updates are always triggered by external systems that only know the Natural Key**) and I want to avoid (if possible) the overhead of having to first read the Entity via the natural key before being able to update / delete it.

I cannot convert the Natural Key itself as the clustered Index as the key values are essentially random and I will face Page Splits for Inserts.

**Edit:** I already have a working solution where after running the migration, I manually recreated the table in the DB with a unique index on `NaturalKeyId` instead of Clustered Index.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For Microsoft SQL Server, you can use the fluent API to configure the primary key as non-clustered:

```csharp
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    
    modelBuilder.Entity<TestEntity>().HasKey(e => e.NaturalKeyId).IsClustered(false);
}
```

[Microsoft SQL Server Database Provider - Indexes - EF Core | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sql-server/indexes)

Comment: Thank you! It works but builds a dependency on the SQL Server provider.